# AWS Ec2 laravel refused connection when disk space became full. Still refusing connection after diskspace was emptied

Tags: laravel, amazon-ec2

We have hosted a laravel based API backend on AWS ec2. It was working fine until this morning when suddenly the mobile app stopped working. I checked the API response on postman and it showed connect ECONNREFUSED error.

I connected to ec2 though putty and realized that the ec2 diskspace was full. I emptied the disk by deleting few project folders which made around 8% space empty. I restarted ec2 but still getting the same error

Can someone please help how to fix this?

Regards
Syed

Comment: OK, upon further investigation, we found that two issues happened at the same time. Disk became full and our SSL certificate expired. The connection refused was because our web server is not starting due to expired SSL certificate.

Comment: Now our second issue is that we have disabled SSL for now but in the configuration file, it is still looking for the SSL module. We are investigating how to disable the SSL mod in the apache. Will keep posted